# Confirmed transaction but unspent

Tags: bitcoin-core

[image]

Hi, I have a serious issue as this transaction is successful but the recipient insists that it's not in her wallet neither did she get any sort of confirmation about the transaction, I have been trying to understand what went wrong and why I keep seeing this transaction as 'unspent'. How can I fix this please.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the recipient's wallet. There is nothing that you can or need to do.

> why I keep seeing this transaction as 'unspent'.

It is not saying the transaction is unspent. It is saying the output of that transaction is unspent, which is perfectly fine and expected. Bitcoin transactions use a system of spending and creating transaction outputs. If a transaction output is unspent, that means it is not spent by another transaction and indicates that the output is available to be spent. This means it is part of your wallet as your "balance".

In this case, you created a transaction which creates an output that is spendable by the recipient. Since the recipient has not spent the Bitcoin yet, the transaction output is unspent. That the recipient's wallet does not detect the transaction means that there is an issue with her wallet, not yours.

Comment: Okay thanks, what can she do to fix her wallet? Any clues?

Comment: It depends on what wallet software she is using. If she has the option, she can do a rescan which will scan the blockchain for all transactions in he wallet.